# A simple but not easy problem: Describe free motion of a stick

Tags: homework-and-exercises, newtonian-mechanics

Assume there is an ideal rigid stick $AB$. We apply a force $F$ with constant magnitude at the end point $A$ of the stick, with $F$ and $AB$ always perpendicular to each other. Note that the motion is in a plane.

---

How can I describe such a system? Is it possible to establish equations of motion for this system?
$$\\$$ I have tried to solve the question by simplifying it as motion of two particle $A$&$B$ with their distance unchanged when F is applying to $A$ and try to get information of $B$. But I only get the information of B in the direction along the stick. Can anyone help? Thanks!

---

Response on Problem-Closed issue: I'm trying to fix the problem. Thanks for reminding and following.

Comment: I agree with you that this may be an interesting question. I'm voting for reopening. Some easy question about simple systems in mechanics, could have a somehow unexpected answer.

Comment: I think if this question asked "how could I find the equations of motion for this system?" rather than asking for a complete solution, it would be better-received.

Comment: Also, if I'm not mistaken the CM of the stick will describe a [Cornu spiral](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Euler_spiral) so that's kind of interesting.

Comment: It could be a special case. I'll add an answer with a small script in Octave. It should work as it is in Matlab, or maybe minor modifications in the argument order in ode45()

Comment: obviously, as soon as the question is re-opened. @CHEN WONG, leave a comment here, so that I can realize when the question is open

Comment: @basics:  If you "follow" this question I believe you'll be notified if it's re-opened.

Comment: thanks @MichaelSeifert, I'm quite new here and I'm still learning how to move in SE

Comment: Hi CHEN WONG. Welcome to Phys.SE. If you haven't already done so, please take a minute to read the definition of when to use the [homework-and-exercises](http://physics.stackexchange.com/tags/homework-and-exercises/info) tag, and the Phys.SE [policy](http://meta.physics.stackexchange.com/q/714) for homework-like problems.